# Questions regarding memory addresses

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stdvector, memory-address

Based on the following code I have few questions:

1. Why the difference between `&s->m1` and `&s->m2` is 4 bytes as size of `double` is 8?
2. Why resizing `m3` does not change the addresses? I expected `&s->m4` to shift further away after resizing `m3`.
3. Why even if I remove `m1` all the addresses remain the same?

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S
{ 
    int m0;
    int m1;
    double m2;
    std::vector<int> m3;
    std::vector<int> m4;
};  

int main()
{   
    S* s = new S();
    s->m3.resize(7);

    std::cout << &s->m0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << &s->m1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << &s->m2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << &s->m3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << &s->m4 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
0x1860c20
0x1860c24
0x1860c28
0x1860c30
0x1860c48
```

Comment: Do note resizing a vector may change the underlying buffer.  It has no effect on the address of the actual vector object.

Comment: Note that the compiler is free to lay out the data any way it likes. Yeah, the objects are probably on something called the stack, but the compiler would be free to allocate them dynamically, under the as-if-rule (relations between addresses of unrelated objects are undefined). And which way a stack grows is undefined, and the alignment may even change with the compiler options.

Answer (score 4):

1. The fact that sizeof(s->m2) is 8 bytes affects the difference between &s->m2 and &s->m3, not the difference between &s->m1 and &s->m2.
2. Resizing m3 does not change the addresses because std::vector uses dynamic heap memory to store the content of the vector.
3. If you remove m1, because the next struct element m3 is on a 8-byte boundary, the compiler adds 4 bytes padding to keep aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Oh.

Well, first, between access specifiers (and I believe in C++11 and later for all items with the same access) the items in a struct are placed at strictly increasing memory addresses, as far as the program itself can tell.

Then, given your declaration

```
struct S
{ 
    int m0;
    int m1;
    double m2;
    std::vector<int> m3;
    std::vector<int> m4;
};
```

… you ask

> **”** 1. Why the difference between `&s->m1` and `&s->m2` is 4 bytes as size of `double` is 8?

Well, an address of an object is the **starting address** of that object, the address of its first byte, i.e. the lowest address within that object.

So the address of `m1` is where `m1` starts. If `m1`, of type `int`, is 4 bytes, then the next item `m2` starts at least 4 bytes higher. And so it did, with your compiler. The compiler is however free to insert padding, so `m2` could be placed even higher. And with some other compiler an `int` can be 8 bytes, or even just 1 byte (it has to be at least 16 bits, so the latter possibility means that a `char`, the C++ memory unit, is then at least 16 bits, as it is on some Texas Instruments digital signal processors).

> **”** 2. Why resizing `m3` does not change the addresses? I expected `&s->m4` to shift further away after resizing `m3`.

All objects in C++ are of fixed size, given by the `sizeof` operator. But they can hold pointers to memory blocks, that effectively can vary in size. `m3` is a `std::vector`, which uses this technique: it  holds a pointer to some internal buffer. You can inspect the size of that buffer via the `.capacity()` method. You can check how much of it is currently used via the `.size()` method.

> **”** 3. Why even if I remove `m1` all the addresses remain the same?

If that observation is correct, the presumably `m2`, of type `double`, with your compiler and compilation options has an **alignment** of 8 bytes. That is, that a `double` must be be placed on an address that is multiple of 8. And since there is still `m0` of type `int` before `m2`, and since with your compiler an `int` is 4 bytes, the compiler insert 4 bytes of **padding**.

The compiler can't move those items around for better space utilization, because the C++ standard requires it to place them in increasing address order, since there is no intervening access specifier.

However, most compilers support various `#pragma`s to influence their padding and alignment decisions.